# ArcGIS Append tool imports attributes incorrectly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, append

I'm working on a project where I routinely truncate and load data from a source annotation feature class to a target annotation feature class. My method is simple, and runs as follows:

1. Delete Rows tool on target FC
2. Append tool to append all data from new source FC to target FC.

Below is a screenshot of some key attributes from the source feature class:[image]

Now, here is a screenshot of the target feature class, after all of the above data has been appended into it:
[image]

You will see that:

1. **AnnotationClassID** has inverted attributes. "Insert" is appended where "Main" should be, and vice versa.
2. **FontName** is now "Arial", when it should be "Verdana"
3. **FontSize** is populated with seemingly random number values.
4. **TextString** attribute is appended correctly

This is the only set of feature classes I've come across where a truncate and load executes incorrectly, and I can't figure out why, nor do I know where to begin to troubleshoot it.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.

Comment: this is a new one for me. so, my first thoughts were to look at arcmap's global settings for text. is the default font arial? is there something in the map document that's set to arial and those font sizes that would throw it off that way? my other thought was that i encounter these kinds of issues when i am geoprocessing with data that has a join on it. is anything joined or related? finally, is your attribute table acting weird? if you try to select multiple rows does it only select one? if so close arcmap, try starting over with fresh settings.

Comment: If you're deleting *all* the rows first can you simply delete the feature class and then Copy_management the annotation? I've found Annotation features to be a **pain**. I found despite what's in the table the Blob can have different attributes, trouble is as soon as you move or edit the text the table attributes get applied to the Anno Blob. Have you tried the Simple Data Loader? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n0000003t000000 or load from XML Recordset?

Comment: Can you use the Append Annotation Feature Classes tool instead? You'll need at least a Standard License to access this tool: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append-annotation-feature-classes.htm